# (Azure) Data Factory to Data warehouse - Dynamically name the landing tables and schemas

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, parallel-data-warehouse

I plan to move data from a number of databases periodically using Azure Data Factory (ADF) and i want to move the data into Azure Parallel Data-Warehouse (APDW). However the 'destination' step in the ADF wizard offers me 2 functions; 1- in the case where data is retrieved from a view you are expected to map the columns to an existing table, and 2- when the data comes from a table you are expected to generate a table object in the APDW.

Realistically this is too expensive to maintain and it is possible to erroneously map source data to a landing zone.

**What i would like to achieve is an algorithmic approach using variables to name schemas, customer codes and tables.**

After the source data has landed i will be transforming it using our SSIS Integration Runtime. **I am wondering also whether a SSIS package could request source data instead of an ADF pipeline.**

1. *Are there any resources about connecting to on premises IRs through SSIS objects?*
2. *Can the JSON of an ADF be modified to dynamically generate a schema for each data source?*

Comment: For ADF Wizard  "1- in the case where data is retrieved from a view you are expected to map the columns to an existing table, and 2- when the data comes from a table you are expected to generate a table object in the APDW."   1 is right, because ADF doesn't support auto generate table for views. 2 is not exactly right. For table, you could also map it to existing table. You could use the toggle link to below the table name to toggle existing table/ new table.

Answer (score 0):

For your question #2, Can the JSON of an ADF be modified to dynamically generate a schema for each data source:

You could put your generate table script in [precopyscript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#azure-sql-data-warehouse-as-sink).

Comment: I see what you are saying about preCopyScript, the definition of this object does suggest that it could be used for such. However, ultimately what i want is a programmatic approach which uses variables and iterates per customer. For that to happen the logic would need to be at a higher level than a single pipeline and as far as i know it is currently not possible to parameterise a pipeline for multiple integration-runtimes.

Comment: I think maybe you could use foreach activity + copy activity, and make preCopyScript as a parameters?